# Overloaded method value udf with alternatives

Tags: linux, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, databricks

I am trying to register a table in Databricks Community Edition using the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val getDataUDF(url: String):Unit = udf(getData(url: String):Unit)
```

However, I get an error:

> overloaded method value udf with alternatives:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your UDF syntax looks a bit strange, you shouldn't define the type when calling `getData()`. In addtion, the input to the UDF should be inside the method itself.

For example, you have a method `getData` like this (it should have a return value):

```
def getData(url: String): String = {...}
```

To make it into an udf, there are two ways:

1. Rewrite `getData` as a function

   ```
   val getData: (String => String) = {...}
   val getDataUDF = udf(getData)
   ```
2. Call the `getData` method inside the udf

   ```
   val getDataUDF = udf((url: String) => {
     getData(url)
   })
   ```

Both of these ways should work, personally I think method 1 looks a bit better.

Comment: I would suggest to define `val getData` in Method 1 (i.e. define a function). What you do is to define a method which returns a function. But this function is always the same, so there is no need to use `def` in my opinion

Comment: @RaphaelRoth That is a valid point. I changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: THANK YOU.  But ... I believe the problem I had was that we can not use the same signature in the def as in the registration. val getDataUDF(url: String):Unit = udf(getData(url: String):Unit)  SHOULD BE INSTEAD val getDataUDF(url: String):Unit = udf(getData(_: String):Unit)  BUT NOW THAT I RESOLVED THAT ERROR I AM GETTING AN EXCEPTION 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported which i will now research.  THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: @user3439308 I believe the problem is that having Unit as return value from an UDF doesn't make sense. You need to return something to put in the dataframe.